# Any way to copy the schema from one MySQL database to another?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I have a MySQL database that contains almost 100 tables.

I want to set up N additional MySQL databases on the same server, each running on a different port. And I want each additional database to have the same schema/table structures as the original database.

Is there any way to automatically make N duplicates of the original database and set them up on N different ports?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [**mysqldump**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) and it's `--no-data` option to get a copy of the schema. Once you have that you will have to make a script to source in mysql

e.g.

`mysqldump  --no-data -u user -p database >database-schema.sql`

will generate a copy of the schema for database `database`.

If you had a script like below in a file called for example makedbs.sql

`create database N;`

[set permissions here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mysql/mysql-script-create-database-script-user-grant-local-remote)

`use N;`

`source database-schema.sql;`

`create database N1;`

[set permissions here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mysql/mysql-script-create-database-script-user-grant-local-remote)

`use N1;`

`source database-schema.sql;`

Then you could run mysql and source makedbs.sql

```
mysql -u user -p

mysql> source makedbs.sql
```

which would create 2 databases N and N1 which have the same schema as your original.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the schema of an existing database using [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) with the [`--no-data` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) and then use this to create new databases using a simple script that creates each database and then populates it from the output of mysqldump.